# Sugar and Salt Solutions

Tags: bread, dough, sugar, salt

When making bread dough, can sugar and salt solutions be used or should the sugar and salt be added dry?

Comment: In a very good recipe for pizza base the requested salt was to be added in solution.  And the brewee's yeast in a separate solution.  This might be related to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Either is fine, so long as you account for the liquid.

I normally add dry sugar or (rarely) salt at an early enough stage that the "proto-dough" is effectively still liquid and they will quickly dissolve, so it makes little difference. If adding at a later stage, a solution might be preferable for even distribution. *Bring on the uptight bakers claiming you can't add stuff later (guess what, it still comes out bread...)* And, of course, when using honey, molasses, or syrup, it's a solution whenever you add it.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to?  If you did (I can't see it being a problem), you would need to reduce the amount of water equal to the amount of solution you are using, so as not to over-hydrate.

Comment: I have always taken the position that dissolving the sugar and salt in the water before adding the water to the flour would give a better distribution of the two solids in the dough.  Also, I am thinking about weighing all ingredients as an approach to better consistency, just as a chemist would measure a volume of solution (or weigh it if you know the density).  It appears from the comments that there are no pitfalls from the solution approach.